# Ruby on Rails: Errno::EACCES after few hours of operation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Ruby on Rails website.  It was working without problems for a few months, then suddenly in the last few weeks it has started displaying the following error:

```
Errno::EACCES in WelcomeController#index
Permission denied - /home/userName/appName/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
```

This is fixed by running the command 'touch tmp/restart.txt', but the problem re-appears after a few hours.

I can't see anything in the log to indicate what is causing the problem, but I am not a Ruby on Rails developer so I'm not sure what to look for.

There is some suspicion that the site is being deliberately sabotaged although personally I find it unlikely.

If someone could help me to work out what the problem is I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the permissions/user of `tmp` directory properly set? According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8135514/1860929), doing a `chmod 777` might solve it.

```
sudo chmod 777 tmp
```

In any case, does apache/nginx have access to read over `/home/userName/appName/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`? As you said, it could be someone making changes to the live code, thus changing the permission/ownership unknowingly.

Comment: I tried changing the log file to 777, but it didn't help.  But I noticed /home/userName/appName/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb had 700 permissions, which seems strange.  So I changed them to 644 like the other files, which seems to have fixed the problem.  

I'll monitor it for a couple of days and if the problem doesn't come back I'll mark this question as answered.

What I don't understand is why this problem has only just started occurring and why it only appears intermittently.

Comment: It could be one of the downstream users who has an incorrect file permission set. Check for the permission in a locally checked out copy of your repo, the permission might have been checked in erroneously. Correct that and make a commit if that is the case.

Comment: Changing the permission of application.html.erb seems to have fixed it.  It's a mystery why this became a problem in the first place, but thanks for your help in solving it!

Comment: @alexrees Verify the file permission in your repo as well, most probably you will need to update it there as well.